# How to edit column values in all rows based on condition of another column?

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

`dataframe` in python/jupyter, where in one column `side` the line is either delta+ or delta-. One of the other columns has absolute values in it `PV01`.

I want to create an extra column and populate it with: `IF` side `== delta-` populate with (`0 - PV01`), i.e. just convert the value into a negative. And `IF` side `== delta+` then populate with same value as `PV01`.

Comment: If its a dataframe, please add sample data, your expected output and also your attempted code.

Answer (score 0):

This answers your question but I'm not sure if it will help,

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'delta': [-1,1,-1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df,"\n\n")
df['col_new'] = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['delta'][i] > 0:
        df['col_new'][i] = df['col1'][i]
    else:
        df['col_new'][i] = -df['col1'][i]

print(df)
```

which returns

```
   col1  delta
0     1     -1
1     2      1
2     3     -1 


   col1  delta  col_new
0     1     -1       -1
1     2      1        2
2     3     -1       -3
```

Comment: That is exceptionally helpful but unfortunately the delta column are strings (‘delta-) rather than integers so i cant use the >0 argument.  If i try and use ... [i] == ‘delta-‘ i get a keyerror 0

Comment: @FreddieC mmmm, that's why we ask for a reproducible example for questions.  I'll take another look at it.  In the mean time, I'd suggest using code to replace the string with its appropriate number using an if else code; if string == 'delta-' replace string with -1 etc...

Comment: Sorry this website is blocked as read only from my work pc so I'm trying to use my phone. Appreciate the help will come back when I can ask things properly.